# Rails 4 - belong_to nested object fields are not saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, strong-parameters, belongs-to

Note: I've read a couple posts similar to this. But non of the solutions works for me.
I have two objects Appeal and Appealer with one to many relationship. When I save the Appeal object all fields are saved and also the appealer id is saved (as FK). But in the Appealer table a new record is saved with no data except for id.

**MODEL**

```
class Appeal < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :appealer, :autosave => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :appealer
end

class Appealer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :appeals, :autosave => true
end
```

**AppealsController**

```
class AppealsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        respond_with Appeal.all
    end

    def create
        appealer = Appealer.create(appealer_params)
        @appeal = Appeal.create(appeal_params)
        @appeal.appealer = appealer


        if @appeal.save
          respond_with @appeal
        else
          respond_with {:error}
        end
    end

    def show
        respond_with Appeal.find(params[:id])
    end

    private
    def appeal_params
        params.require(:appeal).permit(:subject, :status, :submit_means, :card_type, :submit_date, :relationship, :report_date, :explanation, :email_approval)
    end
    def appealer_params
        params.require(:appeal).permit(appealer: [:appealer_id, :first_name, :last_name])
    end
end
```

**EDIT**
Here is the json I use

```
{
        "id": 21,
        "subject": "axxxscaaaa",
        "status": "happy",
        "submit_means": "DOAR",
        "card_type": "sdsd",
        "submit_date": 1466629200000,
        "relationship": null,
        "report_date": 1466542800000,
        "explanation": "sdsd",
        "email_approval": null,
        "appealer": {"first_name":"aaaaaaa", "last_name":"fffff"},
        "selfRequest": false,
        "created_at": 1465851600000,
        "updated_at": 1465333200000
    }
```

I don't understand why the fields of appealer are not saved

Comment: have you gonna through http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast

Comment: Yes I already went through this example and it didn't worked.

Comment: Can you use `appealer_attributes` in `appealer_params`? Like this         `params.require(:appeal).permit(appealer_attributes: [:appealer_id, :first_name, :last_name])`. And I believe you are already using `fields_for` for `appealer`?

Comment: You might want to post your form view

Comment: Are you receiving the params on the controller request? What are your params after the permit ?

Comment: When you use accepts_nested_attributes_for you don't need to create the child model manually, it does it for you. You do however need to allow the parameters correctly. Can you post your 'new' action controller code and also the HTML of the form itself.

Comment: @oreoluwa I don't use form view. I edit the question please see the json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As you JSON object showing, you are not using rails fields_for or something on view form. So you don't need this(   **accepts_nested_attributes_for :appealer** ) line in your model. Model should be like this:

  ```
    class Appeal < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :appealer, :autosave => true
    end
  ```
- Next thing, in your current logic,for your appealer_params, change appealer_params method with this:

  ```
  def appealer_params
    params.require(:appealer).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
  end
  ```
- Create action logic for your scenario:

  ```
  def create
    @appeal = Appeal.new(appeal_params)
    if appealer_params.present?
      appealer = Appealer.create(appealer_params)      
      @appeal.appealer = appealer
    end

    if @appeal.save
      respond_with @appeal
    else
      respond_with {:error}
    end
  end
  ```

Comment: and leave the rest of the code as is? If I do that I get an error "param is missing or the value is empty: appealer"

Comment: Yes in you current scenario, you can leave the code as it is. But if it possible to receive blank values for appealer's data or no appealer data. Then you need to handle it . Give me exact scenario then I will update my answer.

Comment: The appealer can be null (no data at all) but if there is appealer then all 3 fields must be with values.

Comment: I still get error "param is missing or the value is empty: appealer". What am I missing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116383/discussion-between-devd-and-nufar).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def appeal_params
   params.require(:appeal).permit(:subject, :status, :submit_means, :card_type, :submit_date, :relationship, :report_date, :explanation, :email_approval, appealers_attributes: [:id, :first_name, :last_name] )
end
```

and remove this line `appealer = Appealer.create(appealer_params)`

Comment: Ok i got. This is the issue of field_for.